# Comparing values in nested list

Tags: python, list, indexing, nested

I have checked around and cannot find the easiest answer to this.

I have a nested list of items in python.

```
[['screens\\achieve.png', 378, 40, 194, 198, 234],
 ['screens\\test.png', 378, 40, 1, 8, 15],
 ['screens\\cutout.png', 378, 40, 4, 8, 14],
 ['screens\\sample.png', 378, 40, 1, 6, 12]]
```

These are pixel colours from images and I have around 60 images in the list, this is a snip of it.
Image name, x coord, y coord, red, green, blue values

What my tool does is display an image. I click a location in the image and it loops through the folder full of images and outputs the colour values at the location I clicked in the viewed image.

Now what I want to do is look through the list of colour values to see if any other image in the list has the same colour at the same location.

I know the record im checking. From the snippet above, lets say im viewing test.png (item[1]) in the list. I need to loop through the other items in the list to see if the location I clicked in test.png is unique in colour to any other item.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So the output for this sample should be `False`? Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: Its hard to explain. Im writing a tool that helps me find unique colour pixels in an image. I view the image using opencv and a mouse click event. I take the colour values from the click location. I then loop through all the images in my folder and check the colour values at the same location in each image. I want to find that where I clicked is not equal in colour [3], [4], [5] of each other image. Its to help me identify pages in a screen reader. this pixel is r,g,b so this page is page 1 (because no other page has the same pixel colour at x/y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to check the color of image at specific index against all other images:

```py
lst = [
    ["screens\\achieve.png", 378, 40, 194, 198, 234],
    ["screens\\test.png", 378, 40, 1, 8, 15],
    ["screens\\cutout.png", 378, 40, 4, 8, 14],
    ["screens\\sample.png", 378, 40, 1, 6, 12],
]


def check(lst, test_idx):
    *_, r, g, b = lst[test_idx]

    return any(
        (r, g, b) == (tr, tg, tb)
        for i, (*_, tr, tg, tb) in enumerate(lst)
        if i != test_idx
    )


print(check(lst, 1))
```

Prints:

```
False
```

---

If the list is:

```py
lst = [
    ["screens\\achieve.png", 378, 40, 1, 8, 15],
    ["screens\\test.png", 378, 40, 1, 8, 15],
]
```

Then:

```py
print(check(lst, 1))
```

Prints:

```
True
```